# How to Design an Library Application with Rest Api including database

Tags: java, sql, spring, rest

If you were designing an library application lets a citizen borrow  & return books how would you design it from the database perspective.

I did this i created a Book Class

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private Integer numberOfCopies;
```

and when a user makes a request to citizen/borrow/{id} (With Book id The numberOfCopies variable adds one up or down

```
@GetMapping(path = "citizen/borrow/{id}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public Book borrowBook(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    Book book = bookRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException(id));
    Integer numberOfCopies = book.getNumberOfCopies();
    if (numberOfCopies == 0) throw new BookNotAvailableException();
    book.setNumberOfCopies(numberOfCopies - 1);
    bookRepo.save(book);
    return book;
}
```

how would you realize such an application? Is this good programming style or what you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First**, according to REST practices, your endpoint (or resource) should be self-descriptive.

This path `citizen/borrow/{id}` looks like you are borrowing citizens, not books. It would make more sense to make resource like this: `/v1/book/{id}/borrow` as a POST request because modifying query will be executed.

> **Second**, move your reusable logic into `@Service` layer.

I have a rule to never inject the repository into controllers. All saves and updates should be handled in the service layer and return a [DTO](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171479/346745) (Data Transfer Object).

> **Third**, handle your input in your controller layer.

Your `@PathVariable` may be null. This can cause problems deeper in the code. Why not just handle it right away and throw an exception from the beginning?

```
if (id == null)
    throw new new BookNotFoundException();
```